# Typekit font-family doesn't load

Tags: css, typekit

I'm trying to include the myriad pro condensed from typekit, however for some reason this doesn't work. I'm new to Typekit, so I don't know why it isn't working. I believe it's not loading the font off of Typekit, because it's using sans-serif, not the default font. Here is the header:

```
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/rvf7mow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
        <title>PDF</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://raftcolorado.org/css.css">
</head>
```

and the CSS code:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-family:"myriad-pro-condensed", sans-serif;
}

#logo{
    width:810px
    }

#saveDateText{
    position:relative;
    top:30px;
    left:80px;
    font-size:50px;
    color:rgb(228,242,214)
}

#october{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:90px;
    font-size:35px;
    color:rgb(228,242,214)
}

#raftLogo{
    position:relative;
    top:-125px;
    left:550px;
}

#saveTheDate {
    background-color:rgb(123, 190, 48);
    height:170px;
    width:810px;
}

#honoring {
    position:relative;
    background-color:rgb(9, 65, 30);
    width:810px;
    top:-30px;
    font-size:20px;
    height:400px;
}

#honoringTextDiv {
    position:relative;
    width:740px;
    left:70px;
    top:50px
}

#infoText {
    color:white;
    font-size:25px;
}

#honoringText {
    color:rgb(242, 183, 51);
}

#benifit{
    color:white;
    font-size:25px
}

#morgridge {
    position:relative;
    top:20px
}
#sponsorships {
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
    top:-30px;
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-right-color:rgb(160, 202, 129);
    border-right-width:1px;
}

#inventiveSponsorsDiv {
    position:relative;
    left:425px;
    top:-155px
}
#dmns {
    position:relative;
    top:-40px;
}
#1stbank {
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
}

#inspirationalSponsors, #inventiveSponsors{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    color:rgb(123,190,48);
    font-size:18px;
}
#inventiveSponsors {
    top:-20px;
}

#names, #names2 {
    line-height:25px;
    font-size:14px

}
#names2 {
    position:relative;
    top:-90px;
    left:160px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: perhaps there is info in that exception that you are catching? try adding a console.log(e) in that catch block.

Comment: No, I didn't get anything.

Comment: did you run through the troubleshooting guide? http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/807568-troubleshooting-guide

Comment: Thanks for that, new question, is there anyway to include this is a news letter?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by that, but if you mean you want to like email it or something like that... i don't think so, but i don't know for sure.

Comment: Okay, it's now working on Chrome but not Safari, where I need it to work.